# Moving ActionBar layout is moving the visual layout but buttons can still be clicked

Tags: android

I have a DrawerLayout and an ActionBar that I am assigning a custom layout:

`mActionBar.setCustomView(new ActionBarContentView(getBaseContext()));`

When the navigation drawer is opened I animate the layout of the ActionBar to offset it against the drawer being opened:

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    slideActivityContent(drawerView,slideOffset);
}
private void slideActivityContent(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {     
    float moveFactor = (getActivityNetworkListFrameLayout().getWidth() * slideOffset);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActivityContentFrameLayout().setTranslationX(moveFactor);
        mActionBar.getCustomView().setTranslationX(moveFactor);
    } else {
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(mLastTranslate, moveFactor, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        translateAnimation.setDuration(0);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        getActivityContentFrameLayout().startAnimation(translateAnimation);
        mActionBar.getCustomView().startAnimation(translateAnimation);

        mLastTranslate = moveFactor;
    }
}
```

This all works as expected in terms of the visual layout. HOWEVER, I have 3 buttons on the ActionBar and when the visual layout of the actionbar is moved I can still select the 3 buttons. This means when the navigation drawer is open I still select the actionbar buttons instead of what is on the navigation drawer layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating a View (*even with setFillAfter(true)*) does **not** change it's actual LayoutParams, which means:

Even though the View *appears* to be somewhere else, it (and its Touch Listeners) is still where you first left it.

The solution is to set an AnimationListener and physically change the LayoutParams after the animation has ended.

```
translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        mActionBar.getCustomView().clearAnimation(); // Clear the animation
        // Adjust the LayoutParams here
    }
});
```